# Windows CMD: "This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated"

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to run Anaconda Python in a command prompt. However, when I do, I get:

> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment
> has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this
> environment please see https://conda.io/activation

I have tried to run

```
conda base activate
```

and

```
 <path to Anaconda>\Scripts\activate base
```

from within the Windows command prompt and it does nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: *[Python is in a Conda environment, but it has not been activated in a Windows virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/)*

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Anaconda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). If you want to activate the "base" environment, you should just type:

```
conda activate
```

However, it is usually better to create a virtual environment first, like this:

```
conda create -n myTestEnv
```

And in order to activate it, now write:

```
conda activate myTestEnv
```

To check the environments that you currently have on your machine you can type `conda env list` in the Terminal.