# Python interpreter is in a Conda environment, but the environment has not been activated

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, anaconda3

Installation:

[image]

[image]

I'm a newbie in Python and I'm facing issues with Anaconda. Whenever I launch Anaconda Navigator it shows Python stopped working and crashes.

Also if I type `python` in the command prompt I get a warning:

> "Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment please see [https://conda.io/activation"](https://conda.io/activation%22)

I have seen such questions before and tried the solutions, but nothing seems to work. I also tried to reinstall, but it's the same every time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Related: *[Python is in a Conda environment, but it has not been activated in a Windows virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/)*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
conda activate base
```

Or create a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/venv.html):

```sh
conda create my_env
conda activate my_env
```

Or install the Python system directly. Download from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-397/).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be two separate issues:

1. Crashing on Anaconda Navigator startup

   Try to update PyQt. For more information, see: *[Spyder and Anaconda Navigator do not open - "Python has stopped working" (Fixed) #10088](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10088)*
2. For the Python commands, try to activate your environment: `conda activate base`.

Comment: I tried updating pyqt and also I have tried `conda activate base` but it did not solve the problem. Is there any way I can completely remove anconda and also python from my system and start afresh? Will it work?

Comment: Uninstall it from `programs and features` in the control panel. And as I said install python without conda.

Comment: If this didn't work then I'd recommend trying to reinstall anaconda. In the folder where you installed anaconda (e.g. C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3) there should be a `Uninstall-Anaconda.exe` file. Run it then install anaconda again and hope for the best.

Comment: @Nima I uninstalled anaconda through program and features and downloaded python through the link shared but during installation it shows me error. I have attached 2 image links in my original query posted above.

Comment: I found `core.msi` inside that folder. Search for `core.msi` in `C:\Users\%username\AppData\Local\Package Cache`. If found, browse for it when the error happens. If not, try to download it from somewhere. This is most probably because you don't have an active network connection while installation.