# This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I just updated Windows to Windows 10 20H2 and when ever I open an `Anaconda terminal` or I try using `Anaconda interpreter` or `python` or try running a python code in an editor, I get this error from `gpython.exe`

```
**Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment.
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

Output image [image: here]

Comment: does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/python-is-in-a-conda-environment-but-it-has-not-been-activated-in-a-windows-vir) answer your question? if not please wait for a different answer as I haven't used conda in a while now

Comment: type `conda activate` to activate your default conda python environment

Comment: It just warns you that the libraries that you installed via anaconda can not be loaded by python code because you havent activated an environment yet. Does that answer your question?

Comment: please see https://conda.io/activation

Comment: I have tried running conda activate on terminal but the errors pops up immediately after pressing the enter key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PC has a Win32/Grenam.VA!MSR virus and the virus has infected your python.exe by renaming it to gpython.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To do so on Windows, run: c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base in Anaconda Prompt.

Windows is extremely sensitive to proper activation. This is because the Windows library loader does not support the concept of libraries and executables that know where to search for their dependencies (RPATH). Instead, Windows relies on a dynamic-link library search order.